# Hiding select is still accessible with keyboard

Tags: jquery, forms, select, hide

Here is my html:

```
<select name = "pincite_selection" id="pincite-selection"  style ="float:left">
 <option value ="1" >Option1</option>
 <option value ="2" >Option2</option>
</select>
```

and my javascript

```
jQuery('#pincite-selection>option[value="1"]').hide();
```

After the jQuery occurs (I have it activate on a click- not shown), it successfully hides Option 1. However after doing so, if you select Option 2, and press up on the keyboard, you can access Option 1!

Comment: hiding an `option` element is completely supporting across all browsers especially IE.... instead of hiding the option it is better to remove it and add it back

Comment: you can also disable the option element, but its not completely supported.  Best to listen to Arun's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
jQuery('#pincite-selection>option[value="1"]').attr("disabled",''); //HTML5
jQuery('#pincite-selection>option[value="1"]').attr("disabled","disabled"); //XHTML
```

It will prevent it from being accesible with keyboard on Google Chrome, will also work on Firefox and Microsoft Edge and only in IE it won't disappear but still won't be clickable.

I find it better when removing and adding options requires extra requests to the server